# Include spring webflow controller in a jsp

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-webflow

Bit of a background: 
We have an existing spring webflow that we want to have ajaxified so that the page can be displayed 
in a "lightbox" (at a different URL) where the user can interact with the flow in a similar way to the full existing page.

The normal registration form sits at

```
http://localhost:8080/csso/customer/registration?execution=e1s1.
```

(csso is the application name)

The webflow in Spring Webflow has an id of /customer/registration.

```
 <flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
            <flow-location id="customer/registration" path="/WEB-INF/views/customer/registration/registration-flow.xml"/>
  </flow-registry>
```

*registration-flow.xml*

```
<view-state id="create" model="customer" view="customer/registration/create">
        <on-render> 
            <evaluate expression="customer.setAcceptTermsAndConditions(false)"/>
        </on-render>
        <transition on="submit" to="confirm" />
        <transition on="cancel" to="cancel" bind="false" />
    </view-state>
```

Now my problem is I need to access this page in two different ways.

1. Directly. Which works currently.
2. As an include in a different JSP page
   (tabEntry.jsp accessed with controller /tabEntry) in such a way that the flow of the form is not interrupted.

How can I include /customer/registration inside tabEntry in such a way that clicking on submit goes through the same flow?

Problems faced:

1. Including /customer/registration by jsp:include doesn't work since /customer/registration is not a controller. Also @include doesn't work since a call to /customer/redirection includes a redirect which sets the execution key for webflow

   1. The form action is automatically set to /tabEntry but it should be set to the second state of /customer/registation to continue with the flow.

Happy to accept design changes instead of hammering it technically.

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to do, but what about subflow?
could you provide more detailed info on the flow of your pages?